# What's the right way to check if an input has a value less than x in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, html, testing, cypress

I'm trying to check if an  has a value of less than x. What's the best way to test that in Cypress?

Example code (that doesn't work):

```
cy.get('.number-input').type('200').should('have.value.lt', '201')
```

I know I could do this with a callback, but that seems a bit messy, especially given how neat it is to test if the input is -exactly- something:

```
cy.get('.number-input').type('200').should('have.value', '200')
```

Answer (score 3):

Chai `lt` is valid (see [Chai.js cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/chai)), but it requires numeric values and `<input />` value is always a string, so you will need to convert it to a number.

Also, the Cypress `.should('have.value.lt', '201')` command is a combination of jQuery and chai operators, which from the error message is obviously illegal (the syntax for `should` params is a bit opaque, you just have to try things out).

So, this works

```
cy.get('.number-input').type('200')
  .invoke('val')                         // call the val() method to extract the value
  .then(val => +val)                     // convert it to a number
  .then(val => console.log(typeof val))  // just to check the type
  .should('be.lt', 201)                  // also compare it to a number
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! It all makes much more sense now. So the shortest way to do this would be `cy.get('.number-input').type('200').invoke('val').then(val => +val).should('be.lt', 201)` then?

Comment: Correct, I just threw in the console.log to show how you can check things within a command chain.